# Sample function in R vector combining

Tags: r, sample

I need your help, I need to combine two vectors(z and Num1 or Num2), so z will 10 in final vector and Num1(Num2) was 90 in final vector.

Code that I have now:

```
I <- seq(1:100)

NA1<-vector()
NA2<-vector()

z <- rep(NA, 10)

Num1 <- rnorm(100)
Num2 <- rnorm(100)

vect_1 <- sample(c(Num1, z))
vect_2 <- sample(c(Num2, z))

vect_1_NA <- is.na(vect_1)
vect_2_NA <- is.na(vect_2)

for(i in I){
  if(vect_1_NA[i] == TRUE)
    NA1 <- append(NA1, i)
}

for(i in I){
  if(vect_2_NA[i] == TRUE)
    NA2 <- append(NA2, i)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "z will 10"? What about `Num1(Num2) `? Do you want `Num1` to be function? Please clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: I mean final vectors (vect_1 and vect_2) will contain 10 elements of Z vector and 90 elements of Num1(vect_1) and Num2(vect_2) vector